# Select values between start date and end date

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with some events and each event have a start date and end date. For example:
Table eventos_sapo

```
id   titulo imagem startDate endDate
1    ...    ...    2011-02-12   2015-02-12
2    ...    ...    2013-02-21   2015-02-12
3    ...    ...    2014-03-14   2015-02-12
```

I try some queries to get the events between some start and end dates, introduced by the user through my web app, but none of the queries returns the event with `id=1`. Let's say that the user introduce the start `date=2013-01-03`and the end `date=2015-02-14`, should return the events 1,2 and 3, but the event with id=1 is not returned by none of my queries.

Here goes what I tried:

```
Select id from eventos_sapo where startDate >= '2013-01-03' AND endDate <= '2015-02-14'

Select id from eventos_sapo where startDate BETWEEN '2013-01-03' AND '2015-02-14'
AND endDate BETWEEN '2013-01-03' AND '2015-02-14'
```

What I have to do, to include the event with id=1, because this event is active.

Comment: 2011-02-12 is lower than 2013-01-03

Comment: `Select id from eventos_sapo where startDate BETWEEN '2011-01-03' AND '2015-02-14'
AND endDate BETWEEN '2013-01-03' AND '2015-02-14'`
try this

Comment: Yes I Know but the event is still active because is lower than 2015-02-14

Comment: Are you looking for OR logic then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read this problem as looking for the overlap of ranges:

so you have data in range: T1 to T3.  And looking for overlap with range T2 to T4. Since they overlap, you want.
However, if data is T1 to T3 and range is T4 to T5 .. no overlap so don't want.

You can do that with this query:

```
Select id 
  from eventos_sapo 
 where startDate <= '2015-02-14'
   AND endDate >= '2013-01-03';
```

So if it started after the given date (Feb 14, 2015), then don't include it.
or if it ended prior to Jan 3, 2013 ... don't include it.
Include everything else, since it overlaps:

As 1 example:
Data ends after the given range start date, and the data start date is prior to end, so it's one of the following cases:

```
Data:           |---|
Given range:      |---|

Data:           |-------|
Given range:      |---|

Data:             |---|
Given range:    |---|

Data:             |---|
Given range:    |-------|
```

Comment: That works fine :), nice explanation... I have tried with more examples and works :). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments I understood that this is what you want

```
Select id from eventos_sapo where startDate >= '2013-01-03' OR endDate <= '2015-02-14'
```

Comment: I missed the second user input date.  This is probably better than using between.

Comment: @Ditto says is true and correct, that´s the problem

Comment: posted a comment, then thought I misread things, so deleted the comment. re-adding it because I believe I did read it right :)  I don't think this works: If the data has start date = "jan 1, 2010" and enddate = "feb 1, 2010", I don't think it would be active, yet your query picks it up. Not sure if OP wanted that behaviour ?

Comment: @Ditto yeah, you're right.  I didn't even notice, he had them mixed around just like the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
WHERE '2013-01-03' BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
```