# Make SELECT of an specific hour using 2 different hours in 2 different columns with DATE format

Tags: mysql, between

I have the following table

Table name **users**

```
id, name, starthour(DATE), endhour(DATE)
1, "patrick", 17:35:00, 19:00:00
2, "gloria", 21:22:00, 22:00:00
3, "david", 22:29:00, 23:33:00
```

I would like to SELECT only the rows that happens for example between 21:00 and 21:59.  I am stuck trying to make a SELECT of an specific hour using two different columns with date format.

If tried using DATE_FORMAT inside WHERE but I can't make it work.

Comment: I am going to try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an explanation of comparing ranges here:

[Select values between start date and end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329421/select-values-between-start-date-and-end-date/28329533#comment45007193_28329533)

I'm thinking this is similar.

so you probably want:

```
where endhour > '21:00'
  and starthour < '21:59'
```

and that should nail any overlap (see my link to see explanation)